# HTML5 Google Swiffy pause on Last Frame

Tags: html, flash, google-swiffy

I have converted a SWF file to HTML5 using Google Swiffy and it works great.  The only problem I am experiencing is that it loops instead of just playing once.

Is there a way to have it pause on the last frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with ActionScript, on the last frame of the animation add this to the actions:

```
this.stop();
```